# Python - File with same name but different content

Tags: python, file, diff

I have two folders, dir1 and dir2. I have to find files that are in both folder (or in subfolder) with same name but different content.

something like: so.1.0/p/q/search.c so.1.1/p/q/search.c differ

Any ideas?

i get files i need in this way:

```
import os, sys, fnmatch, filecmp

folder1 = sys.argv[1]
folder2 = sys.argv[2]

filelist1 = []

filelist2 = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.c'):
         filelist1.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(folder1):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.h'):
        filelist1.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder2):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.c'):
         filelist2.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(folder2):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.h'):
        filelist2.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

now i would like to compare the two lists of files, get the entries which have the same filename and check if they are different for content. What do you think?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martijn answered for traversing purpose you can use `os.walk()`

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
```

And for filename comparison i would recommend **[filecmp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html)**

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'undoc.rst') 
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'index.rst') 
False
```

And for comparing file content checkout **[difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)**

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to generate a list of files in either directory (with paths relative to their roots):

```
import os

def relative_files(path):
    """Generate filenames with pathnames relative to the initial path."""
    for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        relroot = os.path.relpath(root, path)
        for filename in files:
            yield os.path.join(relroot, filename)
```

Create a set of paths from one:

```
root_one = 'so.1.0'  # use an absolute path here
root_two = 'so.1.1'  # use an absolute path here
files_one = set(relative_files(root_one))
```

then find all the pathnames in the other root that are the same by using a set intersection:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def different_files(root_one, root_two):
    """Yield files that differ between the two roots

    Generate pathnames relative to root_one and root_two that are present in both
    but have different contents.

    """
    files_one = set(relative_files(root_one))
    for same in files_one.intersection(relative_files(root_two)):
        # same is a relative path, so same file in different roots
        with open(os.path.join(root_one, same)) as f1, open(os.path.join(root_two, same)) as f2:
            if any(line1 != line2 for line1, line2 in izip_longest(f1, f2)):
                # lines don't match, so files don't match! 
                yield same
```

[`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) loops over the files efficiently pairing up lines; if one file is longer than the other the remaining lines will be paired up with `None` to ensure that you detect one as different from the other.

Demo:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/so.1.0/p/q
$ mkdir -p /tmp/so.1.1/p/q
$ echo 'file one' > /tmp/so.1.0/p/q/search.c
$ echo 'file two' > /tmp/so.1.1/p/q/search.c
$ echo 'file three' > /tmp/so.1.1/p/q/ignored.c
$ echo 'matching' > /tmp/so.1.0/p/q/same.c
$ echo 'matching' > /tmp/so.1.1/p/q/same.c

>>> for different in different_files('/tmp/so.1.0', '/tmp/so.1.1'):
...     print different
... 
p/q/search.c
```